# How to speed up 4 million set intersections?

Tags: python, set, bioinformatics

I'm an inexperienced programmer working through a number of bioinformatics exercises in Python.

One problem area counts elements in the set intersection between name groups, and stores that count in a dictionary. There are two lists of 2000 name groups each; names in the name groups are Latin names of species. For example:

```
list__of_name_groups_1 = [
    ['Canis Lupus', 'Canis Latrans'],
    ['Euarctos Americanus', 'Lynx Rufus'],
    ...
]
list__of_name_groups_2 = [
    ['Nasua Narica', 'Odocoileus Hemionus'],
    ['Felis Concolor', 'Peromyscus Eremicus'],
    ['Canis Latrans', 'Cervus Canadensis']
    ...
]
```

And I need a dictionary that contains all intersection sizes between the name groups, e.g.

```
>>> intersections
{ (0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 0, (0, 2): 1, (1, 0): 0, (1, 1): 0, (2, 1): 0,
  (2, 0): 1, (2, 1): 0, (2, 2): 0 }
```

(`'Canis Latrans'` occurs in element `0` in the first list, element `2` in the second list.)

I've got an implementation of an algorithm that works, but it runs too slowly.

```
overlap = {}
    for i in list_of_lists_of_names_1:            
        for j in list_of_lists_of_names_2:
            overlap[(i,j)] = len(set(i) & set(j))
```

Is there a faster way to count the number of elements in set intersections?

(Hello moderators... Nick, this revised post is actually asking a slightly different question than the one I'm working on. While your answer is a very good one for addressing that question, I'm afraid that the method you suggest is actually not useful for what I'm trying to do. I very much appreciate the time and effort you put into your answer, and into editing this post, but I would request that the post be reverted to the original.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your interest, but working code that needs improvement is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), being off-topic in StackOverflow.

Comment: I second the comment above, but I think the questions raised in this post are still quite specific and useful. I would change the title to reflect the actual question rather than a vague "looking for improvement"

Comment: Also CodeReview is for *complete* working code. The snippet above is not selfcontained. However CodeReview would hapilly review your code, when you have updated it into a complete working code.

Comment: Not sure if it will speed things up but rather than computing `nCr` every time you could memoize the results and compute new values from previous. Or if you could use `scipy.misc.comb`.

Comment: would also replace all those `tupler(lists1[i][0], lists2[j][0])` with simply `(lists1[i][0], lists2[j][0])`. More readable and removes unnecessary function calls and conversion from tuple to list and back to tuple.

Comment: In order to speed this up, I'd need a complete end-to-end example with input data.

Comment: You could also start with what is considered [Pythonic](http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html).

Comment: would use `for v in lists1` instead of `for i in range(len(lists1))`. `v` would directly be the value of the item, you don't need the index. More pythonic, maybe a little faster. Also, put your items in intermediate variables to access only once to the list item. And as said above, avoid trivial function calls like `tupler` in a big loop.

Comment: I speculate your main problem is that you redundantly recompute `set(j)` many times for each `j` -- you do it once for each `i`.

Comment: Brian, I'm happy to revert to the original question, but I think it might therefore need clarifying, with some example input data. The code you provide does on the face of it solve the same problem as mine. But perhaps my assumption that there are few non-empty overlaps doesn't hold true?

Answer (score 1):

**First,** Python `set`s are good at finding intersections (they use hashing), but your code constructs the same `set`s over and over again. E.g. if the two `list`s contain 2000 elements each [Did you mean the outer or inner `list`s are that long?], there are only 4000 different `set`s to compute but your code computes 2000 x 2000 x 2 = 8 million `set`s.

So compute those 4000 sets once:

```
list_of_name_tuples_1 = [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bbb"), ("c", "cc", "ccc")]
list_of_name_tuples_2 = [("a", "AA"), ("b", "BBB"), ("c", "cc", "CCC")]
name_sets_1 = [set(i) for i in list_of_name_tuples_1]
name_sets_2 = [set(i) for i in list_of_name_tuples_2]

overlap = {}
for l1, s1 in zip(list_of_name_tuples_1, name_sets_1):
    for l2, s2 in zip(list_of_name_tuples_2, name_sets_2):
        overlap[(l1, l2)] = len(s1 & s2)
```

Python `list`s are unhashable, thus they can't be used for `dict` keys, so I changed the lists-of-lists-of-names into lists-of-tuples-of-names.

(This code assumes you're using Python 3, where `zip()` returns an iterator. If you're using Python 2, then call `itertools.izip()` to get an iterator over the paired elements.)

**Second,** consider restructuring `overlap` as a `dict` of `dict`s rather than a `dict` indexed by tuples.

```
list_of_name_tuples_1 = [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bbb"), ("c", "cc", "ccc")]
list_of_name_tuples_2 = [("a", "AA"), ("b", "BBB"), ("c", "cc", "CCC")]
name_sets_1 = [set(i) for i in list_of_name_tuples_1]
name_sets_2 = [set(i) for i in list_of_name_tuples_2]

overlap = {}
for l1, s1 in zip(list_of_name_tuples_1, name_sets_1):
    d = overlap.setdefault(l1, {})
    for l2, s2 in zip(list_of_name_tuples_2, name_sets_2):
        d[l2] = len(s1 & s2)
```

This could save a lot of work in the follow-on code which would access it via `overlap[l1][l2]` instead of `overlap[(l1, l2)]` (without tuple construction or hash generation), and nested loops could fetch `d = overlap[l1]` in an outer loop then access `d[l2]` in an inner loop.

Comment: Why would a dict of dicts be faster? I'd expect the tuple construction and single assignment to be faster than calling `.setdefault`, constructing a new empty dict to pass to `.setdefault` and then an assignment.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen the question earlier had more nested loops, constructing pairs and indexing into `overlap` several times/iteration. It'd be faster to lookup `d = overlap[l1]` in the outer loop and lookup `d[l2]` in the inner loop. Even before that, `o.setdefault()` should be about as fast as `o[]` (one hash table lookup) and _I think_ Python uses ref counting to quickly free a new empty set. It can lookup the existing items `l1` etc. via their hashes rather than constructing pairs and generating new hashes. `d[k] = v` compiles to `d.__setitem__(k, v)`; not actually an assignment.

Comment: Thanks @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen! Your question got me to notice and pull the `overlap.setdefault()` call out of the inner loop. BTW building a dict of dicts could also do less total dictionary rehashing work, depending on the data. It'd take measurement to find out how much that matters and how it balances against different memory management and memory access patterns.

Comment: doing the lookup in two steps makes more sense with nested loops missed that before. either way this seems like a more comprehensive answer then the others posted and I have voted accordingly :)   PS. I'd consider anything that uses a [`STORE_` bytecode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-STORE_SUBSCR) to be an "assignment".

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the nature of your data, but may give you a big saving if there are relatively few Latin names common to both super-lists. The method is:

1. Find common names between the lists
2. compute set intersections only between name groups that contain one of those common names
3. The rest of the set intersection counts will be `0`.

Your own solution is slow because of the *number of set operations you perform*: 2,000 x 2,000 == 4,000,000. No matter how quickly Python performs each one, it's going to take time. My method reduces the number of set intersections computed by a factor of 1000, at the expense of some other, smaller calculations.

My back-of-envelope calculation is that you might improve performance by a factor of 4 or better if there are relatively few common names. The improvement will be more the fewer common names there are.

I've used a few things here that may be new to you: list comprehensions and `enumerate()`, `defaultdict`, list membership using `in` and the itertools methods. That chucks you in at the deep end. Happy researching, and let me know if you'd like some explanations.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools

list_of_name_groups_1 = [
    ['Canis Lupus', 'Canis Latrans'],
    ['Euarctos Americanus', 'Lynx Rufus'],
]
list_of_name_groups_2 = [
    ['Nasua Narica', 'Odocoileus Hemionus'],
    ['Felis Concolor', 'Peromyscus Eremicus'],
    ['Canis Latrans', 'Cervus Canadensis']
]

def flatten(list_of_lists):
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists)


def unique_names(list_of_name_groups):
    return set(flatten(list_of_name_groups))


def get_matching_name_groups(name, list_of_name_groups):
    return (list_index for list_index, name_group
            in enumerate(list_of_name_groups)
            if name in name_group)

list1_candidates = set()
list2_candidates = set()
common_names = unique_names(list_of_name_groups_1) & unique_names(list_of_name_groups_2)
for name in common_names:
    list1_candidates.update(tuple(get_matching_name_groups(name, list_of_name_groups_1)))
    list2_candidates.update(tuple(get_matching_name_groups(name, list_of_name_groups_2)))
intersections = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for i, j in itertools.product(list1_candidates, list2_candidates):
        intersections[(i, j)] = len(set(list_of_name_groups_1[i]) & set(list_of_name_groups_2[j]))
print(intersections)

>>> python intersections.py
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x0000000000DC7620>, {(0, 2): 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specifics of your data, an alternative option is, for each possible data item, you record which lists it is contained in.

With such a data structure, for each data item you can quickly determine which pairs of lists contain it, and increment the corresponding entries of `overlap`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can express each list with one long integer.For example, set with the first element, the second element, but no third element can be expressed as (0 << 3) +（１＜＜２）＋（１＜＜１）　＝　６．

then you can compute set intersection by just compute integer & operation.